# Misterious (for me!) box under the car, on the back - Sentra 2010 (b16)

Tags: nissan, part-identification, sentra

Anyone knows what is this box on the photo? I can't find anything on the manual.

[image: Sentra undercarriage]

(Photo is from a newer version, but it's the same as in mine)

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: Owner's manual rarely give detailed info on emissions equipment and/or their location. However, service manuals do since they're written for trained dealer mechanics and technicians.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's the evap canister. It contains charcoal to absorb fumes from your gas tank and reduce air pollution.

You can see another view of it here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5m2aHdW1EqM